# Play Framework 2.0. Upgrade bonecp

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt, bonecp

There is a project in Scala for Play 2.0. I've met a known bug with bonecp 0.7.1 database connections and want to upgrade this library to version 0.8.0.
In file /project/plugins.sbt I've added the following:

```
resolvers += "Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"

libraryDependencies += "com.jolbox" % "bonecp" % "0.8.0-rc2-SNAPSHOT"
```

But after compilation and distrib building I get an archive with bonecp 0.7.1 in it. What should I do to make Play Framework use bonecp 0.8.0?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Build.scala add in in appDependencies

```
"com.jolbox" % "bonecp" % "0.8.0-rc1",  
"org.reflections" % "reflections" % "0.9.8"
```

Answer (score 6):

If it's the same bug, we have resolved it by adding the following to our `application.conf`

```
# There's a bug in BoneCP 0.7.1: It doesn't actually close expired 
# connections until garbage collection, so they leak. If the application 
# is quiet, garbage collection runs may be very far out (days). We work
# around it by not expiring connections.
# See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/RM1QwOFz-2A for 
# more info

db.default.maxConnectionAge=0
```

For completeness, the link: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/RM1QwOFz-2A

Comment: Yes, it's the same bug. But I don't want to use hacks to bypass the bug. I want to upgrade bonecp but dont't know how to.